# Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 1

Tags: validation

I am getting the error below for a validation rule. What am I missing?

**Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 1**

If your role is one of the 5 listed and you are assigned the custom permission, you can change the account owner.

OR

If the Industry is Furniture and the Program is Retail Furniture and you are assigned the custom permission, you can change the account owner.

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
    OR(
        $UserRole.DeveloperName="Client_Growth_Manager",
        $UserRole.DeveloperName="Inside_Sales_Executive",
        $UserRole.DeveloperName="Business_Development_Associate",
        $UserRole.DeveloperName="Director_of_Sales",
        $UserRole.DeveloperName="Senior_Relationship_Manager",
        $Permission.Allowed_to_Change_Account_Owner = FALSE,

        IF(
            AND(
                ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
                OR(
                    (ISPICKVAL(Industry, "Furniture")),
                    (ISPICKVAL(Program__c, "Retail Furniture")),
                    $Permission.Specialty_Retail=FALSE
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Always indent your formula field to avoid common mistakes. Also your are using assignment(`=`) instead of a comparison (`==`) operator, IF accepts 3 parameters and you gave single.

Comment: @Raul In formulas, `=` is also equality.

Comment: Whew @sfdcfox, been ages I wrote any formula. Gotta brush up, jumping to trailhead! Thanks

Comment: Please use the [Contact](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/contact) page to request an account merge.

Answer (score 0):

I think there a few syntactical issues in your formula. in the `IF` expression above, you only have your condition, not your true and false outcomes (I updated your code for you so you could see it).

I think there might be a few other unintended syntactical issues   so I built out the rule based on your requirements.

Try this:

```
OR(

    AND(
        ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
        OR(
            $UserRole.DeveloperName =="Client_Growth_Manager",
            $UserRole.DeveloperName =="Inside_Sales_Executive",
            $UserRole.DeveloperName =="Business_Development_Associate",
            $UserRole.DeveloperName =="Director_of_Sales",
            $UserRole.DeveloperName =="Senior_Relationship_Manager",
            $Permission.Allowed_to_Change_Account_Owner == FALSE
        )
    )
    ,

    AND(
        ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
        (ISPICKVAL(Industry, "Furniture")),
        (ISPICKVAL(Program__c, "Retail Furniture")),
        $Permission.Specialty_Retail == FALSE

    )


)
```